# Creating an expandable textbox in Indesign CS6

Tags: html, css, textbox, adobe-indesign

i am trying to create an epub3 e-book using InDesign CS6.
What i am trying to include is a textbox that expands/retracts on click.

I tried creating one seperatelly in an HTML file, together with CSS and JS, and then tried to place it in InDesign. Unfortunately it does not appear to be functional when i export it into epub3.

HTML code:

```html
<p class="something">
no 1</br>
no 2</br>
no 3</br>
</p>
```

JS:

```js
$('.something').each(function () {
$(this).hide().wrap('<div class="showSomething"></div>').
before('<a href="#" class="showSomething">Something</a>');
});

$('a.showSomething').toggle(function() {
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/Something/, 'Something-Hide')).
parent().css('width', 'auto').find('p').show();
return false;
}, function() {
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/Something-Hide/, 'Something')).
parent().css('width', '80px').find('p').hide();
return false;
});
```

CSS:

```css
div.showSomething {
    width: 5em;
    margin-left: 4em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0em;
    background: rgb(100%,94%,66%);
    color:sienna;
    border: 1px solid #3c8243;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;       
}
a.showSomething {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.25em;
    left: -0.25em;
    color: blue;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is there another way to create an expandable textbox in InDesign? I would be grateful if you could tell me how to implement this functionality into the final epub3 output